# How to find/check whether Gayatri Mantra recitation style is authentic

Tags: mantras, gayatri-mantra, japa, vedic-chanting

Are there any good references online that could be used to check whether a given style of reciting the Gayatri Mantra is authentic (based on a sacred text), or is a modern invention (like a song composed independently of any prescribed method of chanting, that just uses the Gayatri Mantra as its lyrics)?

I'm aware there are several different styles of chanting, in terms of pronunciation and tone. Is there a good site that summarizes these and/or perhaps includes recordings of the different styles?

Comment: this is one mantra that you are explicitly not allowed to chant unless you are a dwija who has undergone upananaya and received upadesha from guru. if you do, all the sins you commit get transferred to the one who told you the mantra (whether you heard it on loudspeaker or youtube etc.)

Comment: I'm aware of the restrictions on chanting it (although it would be interesting to read a reference for what you've said that's cited from a vedic text). What I've asked about here is ways to verify whether a given style of chanting is authentic.

Comment: @mar Can you please provide reference for your statement *if you do, all the sins you commit get transferred to the one who told you the mantra whether you heard it on loudspeaker or youtube etc*

Comment: mantra = mananaat - trayate (it protects one who thinks/chants it). think of a child playing cricket on street. when he hits ball out and it breaks a neighbor's window, what happens ? the neighbor has to be paid money, but child doesn't have it, so whoever gave the bat to the child and let him play on the street (his parents) pay for it. similarly, whatever sins you commit, they have to be repaid by you. only difference is, because you now have mantra, whoever gave you that mantra is like a guarantor for your sins. whoever affected by your sins will go to him to collect the debt.